# How to debug memory consumption of `dotnet publish` command on linux machine running via docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, memory, publish

We are trying to build our dotnet core 6.0 application via a docker file. We are building the docker file via this command

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker buildx build --output type=image,oci-mediatypes=true --provenance=false -t 734656666.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/abcwbw-stg:develop-7700 -t 726616043643.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/abcwbw-stg:develop --progress=plain --build-arg Configuration=Staging --build-arg S3BucketKey=stc-staging.acdn.com/ --build-arg BranchName=develop --build-arg GitToken=**** --build-arg ServiceName=null  --cache-from type=registry,ref=334533333.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/abcwbw-build-cache:abcwbw-stg-develop -f Dockerfile .
```

Inside the docker file there is publish command

```
dotnet publish -c Staging -o out -p:CIBuild=True -p:RunSonarAnalysis=false -p:RunCodeAnalysis=false -r linux-x64 --no-self-contained --no-restore proj/proj.UI.csproj
```

We are running the command on an ubuntu machine with 64GB of memory. While running, the publish command gradually starts using available memory to a point where it consumes all of the 64GB terminating with out of memory error. We have observed this via the `htop` command.

Is there anything wrong with the way we are running the publish command? How can we debug the memory consumption issue? Is there a way get heap dump and analyze it?

Comment: To give more context. The build waits when trying to build the views.dll for the UI project and starts consuming memory